# Force file deletion on windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, file, locking

I have some troubles with files deletion from my C++/Qt application.
When the user what to delete a work session, the selected work session directory should be removed from disk.

But sometimes, the removal fails, probably because of locks (a file within the directory is opened in another application).

But since the work sessions are stored on a network drive (on a linux server, mounted using samba on a windows drive letter), I suspect that there is also network-related locks.

To avoid problems, I use a little loop for files deletion :

```
        QFile::remove(absoluteFileName);

        bool result = (QFile::exists(absoluteFileName) == false);

        // The file system may need some time to react, wait 100ms * 50 = 5 s for operation to complete
        for (int i=0; (i<50)&&(result==false); i++)
        {
            QThread::msleep(100);
            result = (QFile::exists(absoluteFileName) == false);
        }

        if (result == false)
        {
            qCCritical(c3x::Log::General()) << "Unable to delete file : " << absoluteFileName;
            return false;
        }
```

By doing this, if a file deletion fails, I re-try every 100ms.
This solved about 90% of the file deletion problems.

But I still have troubles : even if no files are currently opened, my program cannot delete the directory.

Using the "Unlocker" tool, I can see that the Windows File Explorer have locks on the directory himself.

So, is there any Windows API call that I can use to force the deletion ?

Is there any other way to prevent file deletion errors ? Maybe in the samba server configration ?

Comment: Your antivirus may also be interfering.

Comment: There are various ways to remove the file on the next boot up: https://superuser.com/questions/58479/is-there-a-registry-key-to-tell-windows-to-delete-a-file-at-next-startup

Comment: There is no function to force deletion. If a file or directory is opened without delete sharing, then delete it when the system reboots. If the file allows delete sharing, then you can open a handle with delete access to set its delete disposition and rename it. When the last handle to a file is closed, the file system unlinks it if the delete disposition is set.